# Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"In\" at path \"c_id\"",

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreign-keys

I created one collection and that value Stored in mongodb like below.this is country collection

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b851243c8352016e4b70d36"),
 "is_active" : true,
 "country_code" : "IND",
 "country_name" : "India ",
 "__v" : 0
```

I want to create state collection using country collection like below

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b852a6e91088217804a1996"),
 "is_active" : true,
 "country_id" : "India",[here i want to fetch country collection _id(objectId)]
 "state_code" : "KA",
 "state_name" : "Karnataka",
 "__v" : 0
```

state.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId

const State = new Schema({
    country_id:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Country'
    },
    state_code:String,
    state_name:String,
    is_active:{ type: Boolean, default:true, required: true },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('State',State);
```

when i pass the values from postman i am getting error like below

```
"name": "CastError",
                "stringValue": "\"India\"",
                "kind": "ObjectID",
                "value": "India",
                "path": "country_id",
```

I am passing req.body has like below

```
"country_id":"India",
"state_code":"KA",
 "state_name":"Karnataka",
  "is_active":true,
```

Is there any way to definr or access foreign key in mongodb?I searched everywhere still i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

> Include Objectid in the file as mentioned below

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

> Then you have to pass req.body like this as mentioned below

```
"country_id": ObjectId("5b851243c8352016e4b70d36"),
"state_code":"KA",
"state_name":"Karnataka",
"is_active":true,
```

Comment: And after that you can fetch data using lookup or populate

Comment: i will send country_id  is  India however in mongo_db it should store India objectid.

Comment: But as per your model you are storing country_id as objectid. So why not you use lookup or populate to fetch data

Comment: because no one cannot remember the id of the data.They can remember only by it's name.while i will pass only by name however in background it will access id.